# Theming tooltip hideTimeout in Qooxdoo

Tags: themes, qooxdoo

I'm using Qooxdoo 3.0.1 in a standalone application, and need to change the tooltip "hide" timeout for tooltips on a `qx.ui.table.Table` header.  Since the `hideTimeout` property of `Tooltip` says it is themable I figured I'd modify the Appearance theme (created by create-application.py like this:

```
qx.Theme.define("projrep.theme.Appearance", {

  extend : qx.theme.modern.Appearance,

  appearances : 
  {
    "tooltip" : // from "AppearanceID" for Tooltip
     { 
      base : true,
      style : function(states, styles) 
      {
        return { hideTimeout : 10000 };
      }
    }
  }
});
```

The "style" method gets called, so I know the theme is being used, but tooltips still show for 4 seconds, not ten.  There aren't any warnings on the console... any suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: Ok, after restarting the browser the tooltips now stay up for 10 seconds... I guess it was a cache problem.  Sorry about that, but now Stackoverflow has a record of how to change tooltip hide times using themes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after restarting the browser the tooltips now stay up for 10 seconds... I guess it was a cache problem.  Sorry about that, the given code seems to work to change tooltip hide times globally using a theme.